# Modificar as propriedades do User control do form a parti de uma DLL VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Tenho uma **Library** criada em **Visual Basic .NET** que acessa propriedades de uma `Form`, e até ai tudo bem! O problema é que quando tento acessar o componente `UserControl` do formulário, nada nele é alterado.

Código:

```
        Dim PlayerHD As Frm_PlayerHDStudio
        Dim PlayerHD_X As Int32
        Dim PlayerHD_Y As Int32

        PlayerHD = New Frm_PlayerHDStudio()
        PlayerHD_X = PlayerHD.Size.Width
        PlayerHD_Y = PlayerHD.Size.Height
#Region "Primeiro Controle- ControlPlayerHD_InfoVideo"
        'Loc_ << Location do Controle
        'Sz_ << Tamando do Controle

        ''Declação de tamnho e largura do controle

        ''Loc
        Dim Loc_ControleInfoVideoX As Int32 = 0
        Dim Loc_ControleInfoVideoY As Int32 = 0

        ''Sz 
        Dim Sz_ControleInfoVideoX As Int32 = 1366
        Dim Sz_ControleInfoVideoY As Int32 = 10

        ''Localização do Controle InfoVideo
        PlayerHD.ControlPlayerHD_InfoVideo.Location = New Point(Loc_ControleInfoVideoX, Loc_ControleInfoVideoY)

        ''Tamanho do Controle
        PlayerHD.ControlPlayerHD_InfoVideo.Size = New Point(Sz_ControleInfoVideoX, Sz_ControleInfoVideoY)
#End Region
```

A aplicação não da erro mas o componente que esta na `Form` permanece no mesmo lugar ele não muda sua localização.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adicione os seguintes *statements* na sua última linha:

```
 MyClass.Controls.Add(PlayerHD)
 PlayerHD.Visible = True : PlayerHD.BringToFront()
```

**Se não resolver** tente isso:

```
 PlayerHD.Location = New System.Drawing.PointF(Loc_ControleInfoVideoX, Loc_ControleInfoVideoY)
 PlayerHD.Update()
```

**Ou tente usar a propriedade `Dock`:** (mais fácil e prático)

```
 PlayerHD.Dock = Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Top 'Alinhamento em cima, você pode colocar qualquer lugar
 PlayerHD.Size = New Drawing.Size(PlayerHD.Width, Sz_ControleInfoVideoX)
```

tenta isso, abraços ^-^

Comment: Vlw! a segundo pego perfeitamente.. a primeira quando eu rodava a função o form fechava :(..